# The purpose of mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Whenever I used to setup a server, I'd run:

```
mysql -u root
# Set the root user password for all local domains
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('my_password');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost.localdomain' = PASSWORD('my_password');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('my_password');
# Drop the Any user
DROP USER ''@'localhost';
DROP USER ''@'localhost.localdomain';
# Exit MySQL
exit
```

Recently I've came across `mysql_secure_installation`, which seems to do pretty much the same. Can anyone confirm that I am safe to use `mysql_secure_installation` instead of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose is to, well, [improve the security of your MySQL installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-secure-installation.html). I always run mysql_secure_installation right after I fire up MySQL.